# Contour plot python with dataset

Tags: python, plot, contour

I need help with contour plot python when my z values is magnitude of magnetic field which I have it.. but, I always get z-value must be in 2D. My x values and yvalues is x axis and yaxis.

I want to know how to substitute my data to get the contour plot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided any data, I will assume your magnetic field data is in the form of Latitude, Longitude and MagZ (or something like that) as a csv.

The most reasonable place to get such data from is NOAA's WMM grid calculator ([Link to the online calculator](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml#igrfgrid)). This generates a whitespace separated datafile looking like this:

```
-90.00 -180.00 420.0000 2022.15   44788.48  145.00
-90.00 -179.00 420.0000 2022.15   44788.48  145.00
-90.00 -178.00 420.0000 2022.15   44788.48  145.00
-90.00 -177.00 420.0000 2022.15   44788.48  145.00
-90.00 -176.00 420.0000 2022.15   44788.48  145.00
```

In my example I took the magnetic field strength in 1 degree steps over the whole globe in an altitude of 420 km. You can of course also just generate the grid for the z-component of the magnetic field.

To import this into python definitely use pandas DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd

mag_f = pd.read_csv('models/mag_model_f.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
mag_f.columns = ['lat', 'lon', 'alt', 'date', 'mag_f', 'aux']
```

As a next step I like to convert my DataFrame into a pivot table, as this makes it very easy to visualize the data:

```
mag_table = mag.pivot_table(values='mag_f', index='lat', columns='lon')
```

Using matplotlib's imshow you can generate a 'heatmap' of the magnetic field - and add contour lines:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# draw magnetic field map
ax.imshow(mag_table, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
# add contour lines
contours = ax.contour(mag_table, 20, colors='black', linewidths=0.3)
```

result is something like this:

[Magnetic field of earth with contour lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zz2g.jpg)